# I can't send a private message to a user in discord with node.js

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js, bots, message

```js
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({ intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds] });

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);

    client.users.fetch('266862837308063745').then((user) => {
        user.send('hello world');
    });

});


client.login('token');
```

Hello,
I am trying to send a private message to a user as above but I get the following error. I am using node.js discord.js v10. I need to code a bot that sends bulk private messages. I can get the id value of the user, but I can't send a private message to that user in any way. I tested it on users I am on the same server, but I get the following error. Do you have any idea how to fix my code? Thank you.

```js
C:\Users\mderv\Desktop\discord-test\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\lib\handlers\SequentialHandler.cjs:287
        throw new DiscordAPIError.DiscordAPIError(data, "code" in data ? data.code : data.error, status, method, url, requestData);
              ^

DiscordAPIError[50007]: Cannot send messages to this user
    at SequentialHandler.runRequest (C:\Users\mderv\Desktop\discord-test\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\lib\handlers\SequentialHandler.cjs:287:15)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async SequentialHandler.queueRequest (C:\Users\mderv\Desktop\discord-test\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\lib\handlers\SequentialHandler.cjs:99:14)
    at async REST.request (C:\Users\mderv\Desktop\discord-test\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\lib\REST.cjs:52:22)
    at async DMChannel.send (C:\Users\mderv\Desktop\discord-test\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\interfaces\TextBasedChannel.js:175:15) {
  rawError: { message: 'Cannot send messages to this user', code: 50007 },
  code: 50007,
  status: 403,
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'https://discord.com/api/v10/channels/1004006390626516992/messages',
  requestBody: {
    files: [],
    json: {
      content: 'hello world',
      tts: false,
      nonce: undefined,
      embeds: undefined,
      components: undefined,
      username: undefined,
      avatar_url: undefined,
      allowed_mentions: undefined,
      flags: undefined,
      message_reference: undefined,
      attachments: undefined,
      sticker_ids: undefined
    }
  }
}
```

**New Code**

```js
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS] });

var lists = [
    "790187748891033600",
    "1003969194301337640",
    "447799169629945868",
    "749349915087470683",
    "702149244370419712",
    "615717190574014489",
    "497489241597542400",
    "702149244370419712",
    "844163655578157067",
    "959938516966584440",
    "836861060262264862",
    "771763703145562202",
    "891470731752390657",
    "844848027453095937",
    "975804040665522176",
    "980404278961270824",
    "349084844128600064",
    "860491154079612958",
    "914841215344717854",
    "863728231031111700",
    "949841043338190878",
    "928289387475771433",
    "759069671873577001",
    "558293214768136217",
    "915012095806939147"
]
const sleep = (ms)=>{
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve()
        }, ms);
    })
}
client.on('ready', async () => {
    console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);

    for (var el of lists) {
        try{
            client.users.fetch(el).then((user) => {
                // console.log(user)
                user.send('hello world').then(reso=>{
                    console.log('başarılı!')

                }).catch(err => {console.log("başarısız!")});
        
            }).catch(err=>{
                console.log('başarısız!')
            })
        }catch(err){
            console.log('başarısız!')

        }
        await sleep(2000)
    }

     
       

     
  
   

});

client.login('token');
```

Comment: This is because that user has their DMs closed, nothing your bot can do about that. However instead of mass DMing (which can be abusive to the Discord API) why not ping a role. There's always better alternatives than doing mass X

Comment: I tried to send a message to another user I'm on the same server and even messaged with before, in case the user has dm blocked, but he didn't accept it either. No matter what I do, I get this error when sending a private message. I had to do it because my client asked me for such a bot. Is there any solution you can suggest? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:**

It appears that the Bot and the users were not sharing a server, thus this error was thrown.

**BEFORE EDIT:**

That happens because the user either has its DMs closed or the user blocked your bot.

You can't do anything to bypass this and still send the message. If you plan on sending DMs to multiple members, and want to avoid the error you can add a `.catch()` to handle it.

```
user.send('hello world').catch(err => {console.log(err)});
// leave empty if you dont want to do anything
```

Comment: https://i.hizliresim.com/p53lrzi.png
I have created multiple user id lists but they all fail and none of them are accepted. I added the new code to the location. Do I need to do something different? Thank you for your answer.

Comment: If the user you're trying to message and the bot do not share a server you cannot send them a private message.
Are the IDs you used from members that share a server with your bot?

Comment: Yes. I joined random groups and got the ids of the members in that group. I even created a new account and created a group myself. I keep getting the same error.

Comment: Did your bot join those groups as well?